# My Nav Menu does not work on Mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my <nav> code, the links work on desktop and on tablets, but they do not work on mobile for some reason.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a href="Donate.html">Donate</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the CSS I'm using for my nav bar.

```
nav { 
    font-size: 200%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -10%; 
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}
nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Can you see why it's not working? I've looked up a lot and tried a lot like adding z-index:1 but it wouldnt work. Please help and thanks.

Comment: Define "not work". Also, you only need to set the column size on the smallest size, and it will propagate upwards. You only need `col-sm-3` there. Where is your `row`?

Comment: The Links aren't presented as links. I can't click on them. When I click on the writing, nothing happens. Only on mobile this happens. On desktop and tablet it works fine.

Comment: I dont have a row, but i can get rid of the other bigger ones. Where should I add a row? I never heard of that

Comment: You will get a lot more help from reading the documentation or using a tutorial (there's one on w3schools.com) instead of asking how to use Bootstrap here.

Comment: oh okay, just wanted a quick answer to see if there was something wrong. Thanks

Comment: i found the problem, the h3 under my nav had col-xm-12 instead of col-xs-12